# MSChart axis CustomLabel angle at RowIndex > 0

Tags: c#, label, axis, mschart

Using VisualStudio WindowsForms Form. Creating Chart control in designer.

I'm trying to add some customLabels on charts Axis along **WITH** the default labels.
To do so I add customLabels with *RowIndex* property =1. Thus I see default labels AND my customLabels.
Now the problem is that while the default labels are rotated correctly my custom labels are not.

The Axis property LabelStyle.Angle affects only labels that are in RowIndex = 0, i.e. default labels.
And if I put customLabels at RowIndex=0 - all default labels will disappear.

What I see:

[image]

What I want to see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no way to do that, really. The reason is probably that the developers decided there simply cannot be enough space for horizontal labels, once you start putting them in one or more extra rows..

Here is a **workaround**: Make those `CustomLabels` all **transparent** and **draw** them as you like in a `xxxPaint` event.

Here is an example:

I prepared the `CustomLabels` :

```
CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
cl.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
cl.RowIndex = 1;
...
```

And I code the drawing like this:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    foreach (var cl in ay.CustomLabels)
    {
        if (cl.RowIndex == 1)
        {
            double vy = (cl.ToPosition + cl.FromPosition) / 2d;
            int y = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(vy);
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawString(cl.Text, 
                         cl.Axis.TitleFont, Brushes.DarkRed, 0, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Do use a `Font` and `Brush` of your own liking. Here is the result:

[image]

Note that you may need to create more space to the left by tweaking the `ChartArea.Position` or the `ChartArea.InnerPlotPosition`, both of which are in `100%` and, as usual, default to '`auto`'.

For even more rows you need to change the check to `cl.RowIndex < 0` and find a nice x position value for the `DrawString`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought of that way as last emergency. I think it would be easier for my task simply make all the labels custom and in rowindex=0.